# Tunnelblick cannot load private key file

Tags: mac-osx, vpn, openvpn

I got a certificate from my network administrator and the passphrase for it. Put everything in the Tunnelblick configuration folder, but always get an error:

```
2010-11-20 13:22:10 Cannot load private key file vpn-pass.key: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal:bad decrypt: error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

Everything was copy&paste and it works on a windows machine. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config file, try commenting out:

```
persist-key
```

and add:

```
auth-nocache
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the private key is in the wrong format.  What does the first line of the private key look like?  It should read something like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If it looks like anything else, you'll probably need to have your administrator give you the key in the appropriate format.  Assuming that it's in the right format, you can verify that you're using the correct password like this:

```
openssl rsa -in vpn-pass.key -noout -text
```

This should prompt you for your password and then display lots of information about the key.  The error you're seeing is frequently caused by using the wrong password.

As you may have noticed, OpenSSL has terrible error messages.

Comment: This is the first line: 

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

As mentioned the same configuration and keyfiles work on another laptop with windows. But the error messages are really horrible indeed.

Comment: See if the openssl command is able to handle the file correctly.  Also, make sure the key file is where OpenVPN expects to find it...it should generally be in the same folder as the OpenVPN configuration file.

Comment: 140735079410940:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:466:
140735079410940:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:pem_lib.c:476:

This it the output of the openssl command. Can't get any information out of the errors.

Comment: This strongly suggests that for whatever reason the password you are using is not the correct password for this key file.  If you're certain the files are identical to those on the Windows system, then I'm going to have to defer to someone with more OpenSSL experience.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask your question on the Tunnelblick Discussion Group at
http://groups.google.com/group/tunnelblick-discuss
Post your complete log file from the Tunnelblick Details... window